Naturalised to Spain and wanting to return to UK (home-country) without losing Spanish Citizenship
I am soon to receive my Spanish Citizenship by residency and want to know what will happen if I want to return to the UK after the 3 year mark. I understand I will have to denounce my citizenship to the Spanish Government and pledge myself to the Constitution of Spain and not to use my original nationality again.
I understand I am still a British Citizen. The issue arrives that if I want to move abroad with my Spanish citizenship, I need to register as Spanish Citizen living abroad. If I use my British Passport, I cannot do this.
Am I able to apply for a certificate of Entitlement for my Spanish Passport to return to the UK? Would this be classed to Spain as citizenship or a Visa?
I just do not want to lose my Spanish citizenship.

I’m sure we’ve had a similar question before, IIRC the general view seemed to be that to be legal, it’s necessary to apply to the UK, simply making a renunciation declaration to another country has no effect.

I don't think you can get a certificate of entitlement if you have a British passport.  But it seems to me that you ought to be able to register as a Spanish citizen abroad and then move to the UK with your UK passport -- Spain doesn't have to know which passport you used to cross the border.  But if Spain wants to see a UK visa in your Spanish passport, that is a different story.

I don’t know the details in this combination, but if you are required to renounce your previous citizenship then you must do so with the country you wish to renounce the nationality of, that would be the UK here. You would then end up no longer being a British citizen, with no UK passport, and no right of abode (so no certificate of entitlement). You would become solely a Spanish citizen, and would need to use your Spanish passport for all purposes.

@jcaron I'm reading the rules on Spanish citizenship, and it's not clear to me whether the Spanish actually require you to give up previous citizenships, or just make a statement "denouncing" them, i.e. declare that your primary allegience is to Spain.

@jcaron , exactly. The issue arrives where if I want to return after “pledging my allegiance” to the Spanish Constitiution, I can’t return on my British citizenship. That’s why I am wondering would reporting my passport as lost and getting a “certificate of entitlement” be better? Would this be classed as a Visa or using my citizenship

" When a British national acquires Spanish nationality, they must expressly renounce their British nationality to the Spanish authorities. However, despite its formality, this step has no binding effects in the UK and in practice, a British national can be Spanish at the same time." - Spanish law firm

Do you have to ceremonially burn your UK passport before a Spanish judge, or something like that?

"our lawyer said, just leave it [your UK passport] in a safe place, and never use it while in Spain, there won't be an issue." - Facebook group. Better than anecdotal comments, see a lawyer!

'if I want to return after “pledging my allegiance” to the Spanish Constitiution, I can’t return on my British citizenship.' - Who says? Are you quite sure about this?
